# Need books talking about perfect mapping in topology please.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm studying advanced general topology and have to make a research about perfect mapping. 
Unfortunately,  I can't find anything in the books I know except of its definition.
Can you help me with some names of books talking about it ? 
"The proper map"  is another name of the perfect map? 
I'm really thankful for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engelking’s general topology has a whole section on them in the chapter on compact spaces (Section 3.7 of chapter 3). In the (very useful) index you can find all theorems and exercises that mention perfect maps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 2):

In Munkres Topology the exercises provide some nice properties of perfect maps. They aren't discussed in the main text if I remember correctly.

Comment: Really helpful as a beginning , Thank you so much!